# How to wait until state is updated

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-state

I am working with React and I am having trouble with the state, because it doesn't update inmediately. I know this question has been asked before, but I am having trouble also with dealing with async and await. It doesn't seem to work with that either (maybe I'm not putting it in the right place).

I have a form, and it logs in before updating the errors in the state

Here is the code

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [errorName, setErrorName] = useState(false);
  const [errorPassword, setErrorPassword] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!e.target[0].value) {
      setErrorName(true);
    }
    if (!e.target[1].value) {
      setErrorPassword(true);
    }
    if (!errorName && !errorPassword) {
      alert("You have logged in succesfully!");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input placeholder="enter your name" />
          <p style={errorName ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
            You have not entered your name
          </p>
          <input placeholder="enter your password" />
          <p style={errorPassword ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
            You have not entered your password
          </p>
          <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the values in local variables:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newErrorName = !e.target[0].value;
  const newErrorPassword = !e.target[1].value;
  if (newErrorName) {
    setErrorName(true);
  }
  if (newErrorPassword) {
    setErrorPassword(true);
  }
  if (!newErrorName && !newErrorPassword) {
    alert("You have logged in succesfully!");
  }
};
```

But you should also consider using the `required` attribute instead, to let the user's browser handle it:

```
<input required placeholder="enter your name" />
<input required placeholder="enter your password" />
```

If you have to wait for the state to update, you can use `useEffect`. Remove the `alert` from the above, and add in:

```
setFormJustChanged(true);
```

to `handleSubmit`, and add:

```
const [formJustChanged, setFormJustChanged] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (formJustChanged && (errorName || errorPassword)) {
    // There was an error
  } else {
    alert("You have logged in succesfully!");
  }
  // Don't enter this again until the form validates again
  setFormJustChanged(false);
}, [errorName, errorPassword, formJustChanged]);
```

Comment: and may I ask what would be the way to make it work with async, await, or any other method?

Comment: What sort of asynchronous logic do you need? Can you show where the async part gets involved?

Comment: I was asking for an alternative because for some reason it still doesn't work in the large project I am working (this was a reduction). I think the asynchronous logic would apply, because I should have to wait to the state to update and then ask if there is any error. By the way thank you for your time!

Comment: If you save the values in variables first, you don't need to wait for the state to update, right?

Comment: For some reason, in this other project, I still have to wait for the state to update, even if I save the values in variables.

Comment: See edit, you can use `useEffect` and watch for state changes